# Plural object being equated to an idiom

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

The following sentence appeared in an article: "I would say 94,504 bitcoins is real folding money, but you can't fold bitcoins." A colleague said that it should have been 'are' instead of 'is.' I am torn as to whether he is correct because 'bitcoins' is plural or incorrect because '94,504 bitcoins' is a singular concept that is being equated to another singular idiom.

I think he's incorrect because 'five eggs is enough' is correct and you rarely equate a plural noun with a singular noun; 'apples are orange' doesn't work.

Comment: This is tricky, conflating obvious count- and unit- usages (which is the basis of the witticism). I think you have to have the unit-form (cf $94 500 **_is_** a lot of money) because of proximity. The language is stretched, but that's the punic licence battlefield.

Answer (score -1):

Unless there is some reason as noted by the possible duplicate note, imagine it wasn't bitcons but ducks.  clearly it is wrong to say "I would say 95,000 ducks a real meat, but you can't make a ham sandwich from them"